# How to solve functional equations like the Abel equation $f(h(x))=h(x+1)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

I have just learned about the concept of a "functional equation". So far as I understand, a functional equation is an equation that implicitly defines a function.

I've found an example, the "Abel equation":
$f(h(x))=h(x+1)$

**Firstly: is this a functional equation that defines $f$ or does it define $h$?**

**Secondly, how would I solve this Abel equation?**

**Thirdly, what is the relation between functional analysis and functional equations?**

Comment: Have you tried a google search? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation
has plenty of references to solutions.

Comment: Those references usually explain the concepts in a way that I can't comprehend as easily and quickly as if someone gives me a casual intuitive description of how to do it. That is why I asked the question here.